# Mobile App Api for Magento (Android/IOS)

Tags: api, magento, mobile

I am developing a Magento ecommerce website and looking to develop IOS and Android app for my Magento Store. But not sure how to communicate with store via API.

Can any one please let me know step by step guide to write php script (or anything else) to communicate with my store to build app.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: We're not a code writing service. Please read the documentation and have a go yourself. If you get stuck come back here with your code and ask us for help then. That's what we do best.

Answer (score 0):

go to magento backend

```
System > web Service > Soap/xml- RPC users & Soap/xml- RPC roles
```

create username and Api key and pass these values , Thats all

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a soap user from System > web Service > Soap/xml- RPC users and assign the user to appropriate role.

Then use this structure to call methods:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://1tamas-dev/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('soap_user', 'soap_password');
$result = $client->call($session,'catalog_product.list');
```

You can find more information on magento documentation:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html